# Stored procedure with identity

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My stored procedure won't work, I get an error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_HUGO_INSRTGAME, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near '@firstName'.
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_HUGO_INSRTGAME, Line 12
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@StudentFirstName".
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_HUGO_INSRTGAME, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near 'value'.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure SP_HUGO_INSRTGAME 
(
@lastName as nvarchar(200)
@firstName as nvarchar(200)
@email as nvarchar(200)
@StudentFirstName INT

)
As
Begin

    SET @StudentFirstName =  'insert into tbl_hugo_user (user_email, first_name, last_name, confidence, inspire, creativity, bonus_q )  values (@email, @firstName, @lastName, 0, 0, 0, 0); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() ';
    insert into tbl_hugo_game (user_hugo_Id) value (@StudentFirstName )
End
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lots of errors in the procedure:
**First:** when defining the parameters there has to be a comma after every parameter
**Second:** You are just setting the `@StudentFirstName` the string value but it is an int. From the string I get that you are first inserting the row and then getting the ID of that recently inserted row to the `@StudentFirstName`. For that you have to do something like this:

`insert into tbl_hugo_user (user_email, first_name, last_name, confidence, inspire, creativity, bonus_q )  values (@email, @firstName, @lastName, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

`SELECT @StudentFirstName = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

using that you will get the id and then you can do

`insert into tbl_hugo_game (user_hugo_Id) values (@StudentFirstName )` 
to finish off.

Comment: +1 `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will return a numeric value though and the variable name `@StudentFirstName` seems highly inappropriate/confusing for your assumed usage so if correct the naming should probably be changed to `@user_hugo_Id`.

Comment: Or you could just use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` directly in the second INSERT and save yourself the trouble of thinking up an appropriate name (not that it would be much of a trouble, but still): `insert into tbl_hugo_game (user_hugo_Id) values (SCOPE_IDENTITY())`.

Comment: same as my answer below, i answered first but somebody downvoted it.

Comment: its not about giving the answer, you have to explain a little bit the mistake

Answer (score -1):

[Have to be VALUES not VALUE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

```
insert into tbl_hugo_game (user_hugo_Id) values (@StudentFirstName )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Create Procedure SP_HUGO_INSRTGAME 
    @lastName as nvarchar(200),
    @firstName as nvarchar(200),
    @email as nvarchar(200)
As
Declare @StudentFirstName Int
Begin
    insert into tbl_hugo_user (user_email, first_name, last_name, confidence, inspire, creativity, bonus_q )  values (@email, @firstName, @lastName, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    SELECT @StudentFirstName=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    insert into tbl_hugo_game (user_hugo_Id) values (@StudentFirstName )
End
```